# mysqli and mysql insert into database commands

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody give me a basic full php-mysql insert into block of code for mysqli() and mysql_connect(). Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The PHP manual has excellent example blocks for almost every command.

- mySQL: [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query)
- mySQLi: [`mysqli_connect`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- [PHP/MySQL Tutorial](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql)

The `mysqli` version function usually have an `i` suffixed after `mysql` keyword. [More on mysqli functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 1):

For connecting and selecting a database (selecting is optional):

```
$con = mysql_connect($username, $password);
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Querying:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM table");
if(!$result) {
  echo mysql_error();
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "Row data: " . $row['id'] . " - " . $row['name'];
}
```