# Extract DOM-elements from string, in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [crawling a html page using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946506/crawling-a-html-page-using-php)
>   [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

I have one string-variable in my php-script, that contains html-page. How i can extract DOM-elements from this string?

For example, in this string `'<div class="someclass">text</div>'`, i wish get variable 'text'. How i can do this?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use the [**`DOMDocument`**](https://www.php.net/domdocument) class, and, more specifically, its [**`loadHTML`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method, to load your HTML string to a DOM object.

For example :

```
$string = <<<HTML
<p>test</p>
<div class="someclass">text</div>
<p>another</p>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
```

After that, you'll be able to manipulate the DOM, using for instance the [**`DOMXPath`**][3] class to do XPath queries on it.

For example, in your case, you could use something based on this portion of code :

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//div[@class="someclass"]');
if ($result->length > 0) {
    var_dump($result->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
```

Which, here, would get you the following output :

```
string 'text' (length=4)
```

As an alternative, instead of `DOMDocument`, you could also use [**`simplexml_load_string`**][4] and [**`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`**][5] -- but for complex manipulations, I generally prefer using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @Gordon done *(yeah, that's kind of a multi-time-duplicate)*

Comment: how fast is DOMDocument?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/DOMXPath).

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$someclass_elements = $xpath->query('//[@class = "someclass"]');
// ...
```