# Regex to select all the content within the div

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to build a regex php pattern for a multiline string, to remove the div that has the class of sn_published

I have tried `(?s)<div class="sn_published".*?<\/div>` it works but wont get the entire content within the div. It stops at the very first ending div.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
  <div class="sn_published">

            <div id="snfwid4" class="sn_published_inner clearfix">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                /* <![CDATA[ */
                if(!$.browser.msie||$.browser.version>7){if($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version<9){
                    document.write('<div class="fb"><iframe src="/9jagallery//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php;jsessionid=4C9A788DF2A51CA6C494B8A4150A4605?href=http://www.9jagallery.ng/6999862?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=9jagallery_web&amp;action=recommend&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=168&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21&amp;appId=964432556951162" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;width:168px;height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>');
                }else{
                    document.write('<div id="fwid5" class="fb"><fb:share-button type="button_count" href="http://www.9jagallery.ng/6999862?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=9jagallery_web"></fb:share-button></div>');
                    fbAsyncIds.push('fwid5');
                    fbStatUrls.push('https://www.blick.ch/stats/?rt=1&amp;objId=6999862&amp;type=article&amp;ctxId=1912&amp;pubId=2&amp;cat=news&amp;meta=like&amp;title=See+the+male+celebrities+in+trad%2C+dapper+looks+on+the+red+carpet&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng%2Ffashion%2Famaa-2017-see-the-male-celebrities-in-trad-dapper-looks-on-the-red-carpet-id6999862.html');
                }}
                /* ]]> */
            </script><div id="fwid5" class="fb"><fb:share-button type="button_count" href="http://www.9jagallery.ng/6999862?utm_source=facebook&amp;utm_medium=social&amp;utm_campaign=9jagallery_web" class=" fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=&amp;container_width=0&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng%2F6999862%3Futm_source%3Dfacebook%26utm_medium%3Dsocial%26utm_campaign%3D9jagallery_web&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;type=button_count"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 69px; height: 20px;"><iframe name="fa3d670dae4582" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:share_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FXBwzv5Yrm_1.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df3203d50df82472%26domain%3Dwww.9jagallery.ng%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.9jagallery.ng%252Ff31a62e488eb1d4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=0&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng%2F6999862%3Futm_source%3Dfacebook%26utm_medium%3Dsocial%26utm_campaign%3D9jagallery_web&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;type=button_count" class="" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 69px; height: 20px;"></iframe></span></fb:share-button></div>
    <div class="gp">
        <div id="___plusone_0" style="text-indent: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; border-style: none; float: none; line-height: normal; font-size: 1px; vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 20px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><iframe ng-non-bindable="" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="position: static; top: 0px; width: 90px; margin: 0px; border-style: none; left: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 20px;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1500641915432" name="I0_1500641915432" src="https://apis.google.com/u/0/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&amp;size=medium&amp;hl=en&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng%2F6999862&amp;gsrc=3p&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.m8KuVzGTpkA.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNcaOvNVX1pvUOBoBGzpH6DVnAaSQ#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh&amp;id=I0_1500641915432&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=76330505" data-gapiattached="true" title="G+"></iframe></div>
    </div><div class="tw" style="margin-right:0px;">
        <iframe id="twitter-widget-1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-share-button twitter-share-button-rendered twitter-tweet-button" title="Twitter Tweet Button" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.5f60791584f95f2ec483faec8b16a58b.en.html#dnt=false&amp;id=twitter-widget-1&amp;lang=en&amp;original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng%2Ffashion%2Famaa-2017-see-the-male-celebrities-in-trad-dapper-looks-on-the-red-carpet-id6999862.html&amp;size=m&amp;text=AMAA%202017%3A%20See%20the%20male%20celebrities%20in%20trad%2C%20dapper%20looks%20on%20the%20red%20carpet%20%409jagalleryNigeria247&amp;time=1500641916562&amp;type=share&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.9jagallery.ng%2F6999862%3Futm_source%3Dtwitter%26utm_medium%3Dsocial%26utm_campaign%3D9jagallery_web" data-url="http://www.9jagallery.ng/6999862?utm_source=twitter&amp;utm_medium=social&amp;utm_campaign=9jagallery_web" style="position: static; visibility: visible; width: 61px; height: 20px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
<div foobar>jhuj </div>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126994/1832568) on another question.

Comment: @SahilGulati I want to get the entire `<div class="sn_published">` and ts contents

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse HTML when DOM parsers exist

Comment: Have you tried DOMDocument?

Comment: @SahilGulati its required that i use regexes

Comment: @TundeCanHelp Make sure its a very bad idea to use Regex for HTMLsource string parsing, rather you should use DOMDocument and DOMXPath query, If somebody suggests you to use regex for this then its wrong.

Comment: I'll rarely pass up an opportunity to post a link to [the best answer on Stack Overflow ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't. You should use DomDocument for this situation. That makes your job a lot easier.

You can load the HTML in the Dom, loop through all Div with getElementsByTagName method and filter what you need.