# How to get element like eg. h1 from data passed to view

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have to fetch one element from data passed to view.
I have div with content like this:

```
<div class="disc" id="content">
    {!! $clause->contents !!}
</div>
```

It shows some text where i have element with heading 1 - h1.
How can I fetch only this h1 element which I could use in somewhere else in view?

Answer (score 0):

Better practice would be to have additional column for that heading in your database. Eg. `$clause->title` or `$clause->heading`, but since you're dealing with that problem you will have to extract that heading through DOM parser.

You can find detailed solution to this on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126967/extract-dom-elements-from-string-in-php) question which you can integrate into your controller.