# cannot catch the html tags using regex !

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/how-to-parse-html-with-php)
>   [crawling a html page using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946506/crawling-a-html-page-using-php)

Im trying to find a way to find the html tags.

So i tried to use **preg_match_all** function to find the html tags.

and here is the code what i used :

```php
$code = "<div>This is a test</div>";
preg_match_all("/(<[^<>]+>)([^<>]+)(<[^<>]+>)/",
$code, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

when i used this code, and i try to run it.. the page returned

> array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "
>   This is a test
>   " } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "
>   " } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "This is a test" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "
>   " } }

as you see in the arrays.. the **`<div>`** and **`</div>`** didn't detected.

can you help me ? , and tell me where is the problem exactly.

Sorry for my english ..

Thanks,

Comment: Don't use regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Corey Ogburn i want to use regex this is required for what i want to do..thanks and sorry

Comment: @gpojd this topic not using regex.. regex is required for what i want to do in my website ..

Comment: you're just being stubborn, parse html with an HTML DOM PARSER (ex: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and NOT with regex. IMO stubborn persons don't deserve help.

Answer (score 2):

Please see: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

As Bobince "explains", you shouldn't use regexes to parse HTML.

Since you're using PHP you can check out [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which allows you to safely parse HTML.  Take a look at the reference material, attempt to incorporate `DOMDocument` into your app and if you still have problems answer a new question or appropriately edit this one.

Comment: This is a suitable comment but just saying "Don't use regex" without providing an alternative isn't an answer.

Comment: bobince's alternative is to try an XML parser.

Comment: The question I referenced has dozens of alternatives. I added the last line so that SE didn't convert my "trivial answer" into a comment.

Comment: And adding a link to a PHP HTML parser takes an additional 10 seconds.

Comment: So does reading the link I posted :). Nevertheless, thank you for the edit.

Comment: I'm completely with you on the reading the link.  However, in regex/HTML cases I'm more concerned with the dev quickly grasping alternatives.  From what I've seen of questions like this they're far more apt to just look for a regex that will "squeak" by then actually read deep enough into that answer to get to the "use a parser part".  But, I feel HTML/regex use is sinful enough to temporarily ignore the laziness in not reading deep enough into the answer.

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry; That makes complete sense. I suppose I was just feeling uncharitable since this question has been asked time and time again :)

Comment: Sorry, but its required to use REGEX .