# Regex: match all html tags on line before line break

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm pulling my hair out over this one. I want to get all contents within <a> tags, my html structure looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my regex:

```
/<a ?.*>(.*?)<\/a>/
```

The problem occurs when the the cms doesn't output the <li>'s with a line break:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is some example output of the match array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="/schools/early-years-groups" class="active">Early Years Groups</a></li><li class="leaf first menu-mlid-20328 order_early_years_stuff"><a href="#" title="Order Schools Stuff">Order Early Years Stuff</a>
            [1] => <a href="/schools/early-years-groups/fundraise" title="Fundraise">Fundraise</a>
            [2] => <a href="/schools/early-years-groups/ey-showcase" title="Early Years Showcase">Early Years Showcase</a>
            [3] => <a href="/schools/how-to-pay-your-money-in" title="">How To Pay Your Money In</a>
            [4] => <a href="/schools/early-years-groups/learning-activities" title="Learning Activities">Learning Activities</a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order Early Years Stuff
            [1] => Fundraise
            [2] => Early Years Showcase
            [3] => How To Pay Your Money In
            [4] => Learning Activities
        )

)
```

Thanks very much for any help this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Ah, the never-ending [stream of confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...

Comment: Do you need to use regex for this task? PHP has a few HTML parsers at its disposal that are better suited for this.

Comment: @KerrekSB [oh, the irony…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946506/crawling-a-html-page-using-php/3955436#3955436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is too 'greedy' on the opening tag. Something like this should work better:

```
<a\s?[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>
```

It matches the anchor, with an optional space, followed by anything BUT the closing > of the tag, so it will definitely stop when it hits that >. The same trick applies to the anchor's content, look for anything BUT the < of the closing anchor tag.

Comment: Thank you! I am a total regex noob, this works but selects the whole element as opposed to the contents, or the element and the contents in a multidimensional like above - any ideas? But thanks on the right track :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a regular expression to parse HTML... you will find plenty of examples lying around here explaining why.

Maybe something like [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use a greedy search when looking for the `>` when it should be lazy. Here's an example:

```
<a .*?>(.*?)<\/a>
     ^
```

See it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v60h